# Json value retrive from powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am trying to fetch some values from json array if condition meet

My Json File:

```
{
    "ImpactMitigationTime": 638159040000000000,
    "Status": "Active",
    "ExternalIncidentId": null,
    "RecommendedActions": null,
    "PlatformInitiated": true,
    "ImpactStartTime": 638114093314870000,
    "SubscriptionId": "xxxx",
    "LastUpdateTime": 638120832531660300,
    "EventSource": "ServiceHealth",
    "TrackingId": "VNY4-RC8",
    "EventLevel": "Informational",
    "impactType": null,
    "EventType": "HealthAdvisory",
    "Priority": 22,
    "duration": null,
    "Summary": "<p><em>You’re receiving this notification because you use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD).</em></p>",
    "Header": "Your service might have been impacted by an Azure service issue",
    "Impact": [
        {
            "ImpactedService": "Azure Active Directory",
            "ImpactedRegions": [
                {
                    "ImpactedRegion": "West US 2",
                    "Status": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "ImpactedRegion": "East US",
                    "Status": "Resolved"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ImpactedService": "Multi-Factor Authentication",
            "ImpactedRegions": [
                {
                    "ImpactedRegion": "South Central US",
                    "Status": "Active"
                },
                {
                    "ImpactedRegion": "Central US",
                    "Status": "Resolved"
                }               
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Title": "Action required: Add your IPv6 ranges to Conditional Access policies by 31 March 2023",
    "Level": "Warning",
    "IsHIR": false
}
```

Need PS script to pull value only of Active status Impacted regions
My Current PS Script:

```
 $varNotifications = gc "C:\Users\pocadmin\Desktop\1.json" | ConvertFrom-Json

if($varnotifications.Impact.ImpactedRegions | Where {$_.Status -eq 'Active'})

        {

        $varsubscriptionId = $varnotifications.subscriptionid

        $varimpactedServices = $varnotifications.Impact.ImpactedService

        
        $varimpactedRegions = $varnotifications.Impact.ImpactedRegions.ImpactedRegion

        $varstatus = $varnotifications.Impact.ImpactedRegions.status

        }
  $varsubscriptionId
  $varimpactedServices
  $varimpactedRegions
  $varstatus
```

My Output:

```
xxxx
Azure Active Directory
Multi-Factor Authentication
West US 2
East US
South Central US
Central US
Active
Resolved
Active
Resolved
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: Did any of the given answers solve your problem? If so, please read the [tour] so you can see how to accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't try to fetch the info in various separate variables, but have the code return an array of objects with values that belong to each other.

Something like this:

```
$data = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\pocadmin\Desktop\1.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
# loop through the data and return only objects where the Status for the ImpactedRegion equals 'Active'
$result = $data.impact | ForEach-Object {
    $service =  $_.ImpactedService
    foreach ($region in ($_.ImpactedRegions | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Active'})) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Service = $service
            Region  = $region.ImpactedRegion
            Status  = $region.Status
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to CSV file if you like
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Users\pocadmin\Desktop\1.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

On console screen this outputs

```
Service                     Region           Status
-------                     ------           ------
Azure Active Directory      West US 2        Active
Multi-Factor Authentication South Central US Active
```

<sup>The `-UseCulture` switch lets PowerShell create a CSV file where the delimiter character is whatever is defined in your systems ListSeparator. By doing this, you can simply double-click the file to open it in Excel on machines that have the same regional settings</sup>

---

From your comments, I gather you do not just get the objects where the ImpactedRegion's Status equals 'Active', but you want to filter the results in various ways.
To do that, just have the code output **all** objects and filter afterwards to whatever you find important:

```
$data = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\pocadmin\Desktop\1.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
# loop through the data and return objects
$result = $data.impact | ForEach-Object {
    $service =  $_.ImpactedService
    foreach ($region in $_.ImpactedRegions) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Service = $service
            Region  = $region.ImpactedRegion
            Status  = $region.Status
        }
    }
}
```

Here you filter whatever you need from the data in $result for instance:

```
# get all where the ImpactedRegion's Status equals 'Active'
$result | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Active'}

# get all where the ImpactedRegion's Status is anything except 'Active'
$result | Where-Object {$_.Status -ne 'Active'}

# get all where the ImpactedRegion's Status equals 'Resolved'
$result | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Resolved'} 

# get all where the ImpactedRegion's Status equals 'Active' OR 'Resolved'
$result | Where-Object {$_.Status -match 'Active|Resolved'}  # uses regex 

# get all where the ImpactedRegion's Status is anything other than 'Active' or 'Resolved'
$result | Where-Object {$_.Status -notmatch 'Active|Resolved'}  # uses regex
```

Etcetera, etcetera...
Please read about [Comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#comparison-operators) to learn how to filter results just about anyway you want.

Comment: thanks for the sharing your knowledge.
How can I do the same for other than 'Active' status?

Comment: @Charly In that case just change the condition to `$_.Status -ne 'Active'`

Comment: Tried that. If I need both cases in single script like if Status eq Active or if status eq Resolved. This is where I am not able to fix the error

Comment: @Charly For that do `$_.Status -match 'Active|Resolved'}`

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Suppose if I need to get seperate array results for Active status and it's region, Resolved Status and it's Region. How to do that?

Comment: @Charly Please see my edit that shows how to filter afterwards on whatever condition you want to throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

Your method only gets an array of the form @(), you need to get the value from it.

```
$varnotifications.Impact.ImpactedRegions |Where-Object {$_.status -eq "active"} |Select-Object -Expand ImpactedRegion
```